# Looking for a paper of Lagarias and Odlyzko

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

I have been studying about the Chebotarev Density Theorem and have been hunting for the following paper of Lagarias and Odlyzko for quite a while:

Effective versions of the Chebotarev density theorem, J. C. Lagarias and A. M. Odlyzko, pp. 409-464 in Algebraic Number Fields, A. Frohlich (ed.), Academic Press, 1977.

I tried looking for the paper as well as for the book itself however the only results I get are other papers citing the above reference. I would be really grateful if someone could post a link to the paper, as I am really stuck without it.

Comment: the paper is not online, here is a [list](https://www.worldcat.org/title/algebraic-number-fields-l-functions-and-galois-properties-proceedings-of-a-symposium/oclc/3107334) of libraries that have it.

Comment: Thanks, but the libraries in that list are at least 2000 miles away from me.

Comment: you could ask Prof. Odlyzko, although the pdf is not on his [web site](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/complete.html).

Comment: You can find an account of the proof by Lagarias and Odlyzko, with explicit effective constants, in Winckler's thesis (https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01263765 or https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.5715), and a generalisation (conditional on the validity of the Generalised Riemann Hypothesis) in the recent work of Grenié and Molteni (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2018.12.005).

Comment: you might like this   http://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~lenstrahw/PUBLICATIONS/1994c/art.pdf

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but I will add a link: [lagarias-odlyzko.pdf](https://aareyanmanzoor.github.io/assets/articles/lagarias-odlyzko.pdf). This is in $\LaTeX$ as it was typeset by the [TeXromancers](https://aareyanmanzoor.github.io/Texromancers.html).

Comment: This TeXromancers project is amazing! Any ideas what books they (you?) will do next?

Comment: Please note that the Github link to the dyslexic version is invalid.

Comment: @AlexM. That is odd, the links seem to work fine for me.

Comment: @Vincent We just started working on Quillen's "Homotopical Algebra".

Comment: @AlexM. Links are mysterious creatures. For me it doesn't work when clicking it, but it does work when right-clicking it and selecting 'open link in new tab'. No idea why, but this might also work for you...

Comment: @EmilJeřábek thank you, I fixed this.